# Python requests: abruptly slow in requesting from Nodejs HTTP server

Tags: python, json, node.js, python-requests

I have a NodeJS HTTP server that displays a JSON file which gets updated multiple times a second. Sample data:

```
{
    "MainText": [{
            "field1": "text",
            "field2": "text",
            "field3": 1234
        },
        {
            "field1": "text",
            "field2": "text",
            "field3": 1234
        },
        {
            "field1": "text",
            "field2": "text",
            "field3": 1234
        }
    ]
}
```

Usually after a certain period of time, the number of such entries in this JSON grows to about 200k or more.

I have to import the entire JSON into a pandas dataframe and I am using the following for doing so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(requests.get(url).text))
```

Usually this takes about 0.3 seconds. But for no reason apparent to me, after a few requests, it started taking close to 4 seconds for (almost) the same fixed size of JSON. There is no change in the CPU or RAM usage while making requests.

If I restart the NodeJS server, the problem fixes itself temporarily but comes back later.

Do I need to close the connection to the HTTP server? I'm hoping 180k lines of text is not too much for requests to fetch quickly from the server?

Should I look for a more efficient way of loading JSON data to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Might be a good use case for streams maybe?